# How can I use Clojure libraries in a Java project, using Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, clojure

I would like to import clojure libraries into a maven based java 11 application. The version of clojure used is mostly 1.8+, using boot to build. I can afford to be flexible on the language versions, but using boot for the clojure is a requirement.

I've done some reading into this but I have not been able to find any recent solutions, and non that use boot. Given that they're both JVM languages I hoped this wouldn't be too complicated but unsure where to begin.

Comment: Can you confirm if Boot in this question refers to either Spring-Boot or Boot-Clj (the Boot build tool for Clojure)?

Answer (score 3):

Plain old Maven you should be enough to be able to retrieve any Clojure dependencies, since it supports adding different sources of packages. You just need to add another repo where the Clojure packages are hosted:

```xml
  <repositories>
    <repository> <!-- You probably have this already -->
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository><!-- You'll need to add this -->
      <id>clojars</id>
      <url>https://repo.clojars.org/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

To add more dependencies in Maven, you can search for the Clojure packages in [Clojars](https://clojars.org/) or in [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/). For instance, here's the entry in Maven repository for the clj-time library: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/clj-time/clj-time/0.15.1

The relevant bit for adding that dependency in Maven would be:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>clj-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>clj-time</artifactId>
    <version>0.15.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Once you have the library available as a dependency, you can call it from Java as described on this guide: https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#_calling_clojure_from_java

If you need to write a significant amount of code to use the libraries that you are interested, it might be advisable to write a Clojure function as the entry point rather than trying to write lots of Java code that call the Clojure library code.